# How to call .cs files which are in Azure DevOps Repository with Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

How to call existing .cs files which are in Azure DevOps Repository with Azure Function App. Please let me know the steps. Thank You.

Comment: May I know if below answer helps?

Answer (score 0):

By default Azure DevOps Function task will require you to build your Function Files in DevOps and then upload the build artifact to the Azure Functions App for the Function to be visible:-

***My Azure DevOps yaml pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxx534f3'

  
  functionAppName: 'valleyfunc768'

 
  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'

  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

In order to upload your Files, You can use FTP upload task like below:-

Download the **Publish profile** from ***Azure Function App Overview tab***:-

Copy this part for the FTP credentials:-

```xml
FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod-sy3-105.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot" ftpPassiveMode="True" userName="valleyfunc768\$valleyfunc768" userPWD="xxxxxxHXNWirYnoT8YxDXLl8Rgz"
```

Task:-

```yaml
- task: FtpUpload@2
            inputs:
              credentialsOption: 'inputs'
              serverUrl: 'ftp://waws-prod-sy3-105.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot'
              username: 'valleyfunc768\$valleyfunc768'
              password: 'xxxxxxditQHXNWirYnoT8YxDXLl8Rgz'
              rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
              filePatterns: '**/*.cs'
              remoteDirectory: 'C:\home\site\wwwroot'
              clean: false
              cleanContents: false
              preservePaths: false
              trustSSL: false
```

***Output:-***

[image]